# VB.net: how do i find how close an object is to another?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, game-engine

First off, 
I'm using Visual Basics 2013.

I'm coding a game using VB.net
In this game you control spaceships and 
choose where you want them to fly. And I'm
trying to set it up to where when a ship 
(which is represented by a picture box)
`PictureBox1` and `PictureBox2`.
get within a certain radius of each other
they attack.

I would show you the code, but currently it is just a empty Sub.

NOTE It's not a revolutionary or advanced game, but
it's a small step closer to making better quality
programs.

I thank you for ANY help or guidance you have to offer.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like basic math.

```
distance = Math.Sqrt(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist)
```

Where xDist and yDist are the difference in x position and y position.

You can then check if distance is smaller than some value `a` to invoke your "attack" scenario.

Comment: Math.Pow needs a second parameter, in this case a 2. Using multiplication (e.g. xDist * xDist) to do the squaring is faster than the power function. And there is no need to determine the absolute value here. If a distance is negative, squaring it will make it positive.

Comment: My mistake, I'll edit my answer.  I didn't know that Math.Pow was slower.